# How to call some Objective C code in a PhoneGap app on startup?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, cordova

I have a PhoneGap app up and running using JavaScript and HTML.

On app startup I need to run some Objective C code (I don't know anything about Objective C. I just have some code that I need to copy + paste so it runs when the app starts).

Where do I put that code in my Phonegap project? Is there some kind of event listener or a main function?

Comment: Does phonegap generate an xcode project? Do you have a class called XXXAppDelegate.m/.h ? (XXX acts as a wildcard)

Comment: @Thedude Yes, PhoneGap has a wizard that creates a Xcode project. In the Classes folder, there are AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.m file look for a method called:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //ADD YOUR OBJECTIVE-C CODE HERE
    return YES;
}
```

**Another possible option:**

It's possible that you have other classes, like an XXXViewController.h/.m. If that's the case, check if there is a method called:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //INSERT YOUR OBJECTIVE-C CODE HERE.
}
```

Comment: The 2nd method did the job! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a plugin.  By doing this, you can create native objective C classes and then call them from Javascript in PhoneGap.

Take a look here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-ios.html

Comment: That's not what I want. I want to run Objective C code. Not JavaScript.

Comment: This is showing you how to use native Objective C code.  Look at the class called NativePlugin.  That is Objective C.  You then call the native Objective C from Javascript.  Using PhoneGap, this is the best way to call Objective C.